# How to convert a date in other format?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

I've a date with this format:

```
Mon Oct 19 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)
```

My goal is convert a date into this format:

```
2015-10-19T00:00:00
```

How I can achieve this result?

**UPDATE**

```
var currDateEnd = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start;
                        currDateEnd.toISOString();
                        console.log("currDateEnd iso => ", currDateEnd.toDate().toDateString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
moment().format();  // results in something like : 2015-10-25T13:09:29-04:00
```

You could just snip off the end part if you wanted. (The timezone part, -04:00)

Source: [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

this `Mon Oct 19 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)` is the String representation of Javascript Date Object , so use this function `.toISOString();` like this

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dncmndn/)

```
var d = new Date();
$(".yo").append("The String of the object -> "+d.toString()+"<br>");
$(".yo").append("What you want -> "+d.toISOString());
```

try this

```
var currDateEnd = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start;
console.log("currDateEnd iso => ", currDateEnd.toDate().toISOString());
```

Comment: I've applied your solution but not working the result is: Mon Oct 19 2015 and the hours is lost

Comment: I've updated my question, the result of .start is Mon Oct 19 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)

Comment: okay now working but if I try to set the hours like this: currDateEnd_r.setHours(23); I get .setHours is not a function, I can solve this?

Comment: currDateEnd.toDate().setHours(23)